# Delay navigation in electron

Tags: javascript, navigation, electron, delay, delayed-execution

I'm using electron for tests against my website, and need to delay the navigation process in order to verify the XHR response from the server (navigation makes it impossible to read the response on time and it's being lost on a new page).

**How can I properly delay the navigation in electron?**

I have tried to use [will-navigate](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-will-navigate) event of webContents with the synchronous block. However, it's blocking the whole renderer process and not the actual page, so I cannot actually access anything in the renderer.

```
webContents.on('will-navigate', (event, url) => {
    let blockTime = 2; // seconds

    // Synchronous block
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + (blockTime * 1000)) { }
});
```